# Converting string with indentation to brackets

Tags: python, string, replace, indentation, python-re

I have a variable which has text with indentation. What I need to do is to convert that string to string with brackets. Sample Code is given below :

```
def indent_to_bracket(text):
    ...
    return text

text='''
def main():
    print('hi')
    if(2==2):
        print('games')
    print('yo!')
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        if(i>2):
            print('end1')
        else:
            print('end2')
'''
text=indent_to_bracket(text)
print(text)
```

Output required :

```
def main(){
    print('hi')
    if(2==2){
        print('games')
    }
    print('yo!')
    for i in range(5){
        print(i)
        if(i>2){
            print('end1')
        }
        else{
            print('end2')
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried so for is this but it doesn't work perfectly:

```
def indent_to_brackets(text):
    t=0
    ls=text.splitlines()
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        tab=ls[i].count('    ') # 4 tabs or \t
        if tab > t:
            t+=1
            ls[i-1]=ls[i-1]+'{'
        elif tab < t:
            t-=1
            ls[i-1]=ls[i-1]+'\n'+'\t'*(tab-1)+'}'
    return '\n'.join(char for char in ls).replace(':','')
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? stackoverflow is not a codewriting service. try something on your own before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `tab=ls[i].count('    ')` is does not get the length of the leading whitespace. If you want to do what Python does first replace tabs with spaces and then get the difference `len(s)-len(s.lstrip(' '))`.

This would handle the example but it does not support the wrapping allowed in () where the newlines are ignored. To do that you need to keep track of parenthesis nesting depth in the same way that you do for the indentation depth.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured some way and it worked but it is not an effective way. Hope it might help some of you:

```
def remove_items(test_list, item):
    res = [i for i in test_list if i != item]
    return res

def formater(z):
    i=f=0
    s=""
    l='{'
    r='}'
    o=lambda:s+("\n"+"\t"*i)*f+c
    for c in z:
        if c in l:
            f=1
            s=o()
            i+=1
        elif c in r:
            i-=1
            f=1
            s=o()
        else:
            s=o()
            f=0

    s_ls=s.splitlines()

    for i in range(len(s_ls)):
        if ';' in s_ls[i]:
            nTabs=len(s_ls[i].split('\t'))-1
            v=';\n'+'\t'*nTabs
            l=s_ls[i].split(';')
            s_ls[i]=v.join(char for char in l)
    s='\n'.join(char for char in s_ls)
    return s

    return s.replace('')
            
def indent_to_brackets(text):
    t=0
    ls=text.splitlines()
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        tab=ls[i].count('    ') # 4 tabs or \t
        if tab > t:
            t+=1
            ls[i-1]=ls[i-1].strip()+'{'
        elif tab < t:
            t-=1
            ls[i-1]=ls[i-1].strip()+'}'
        else:
            ls[i]=ls[i].strip()
    text=''.join(char.strip() for char in ls).replace(':','')
    l=text.count('{')
    r=text.count('}')
    if l > r:
        ans=l-r
        text=text+'}'*ans
    else:
        return 0
    text=formater(text)
    return text

text='''
def main():
    print('hi');
    if(2==2):
        print('games');
    print('yo!');
    for i in range(5):
        print(i);
        if i>2:
            print('end1');
        else:
            print('end2');
'''

text=indent_to_brackets(text)
print(text)
```

Any ideas to improve the code then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds all colons at the ends of lines and replaces them with opening curly brackets. Then it finds any decreases in indentation and puts closing brackets there based on how far the indentation lowered by.

```
code = '''#include <stdio.h>

char * text2print = "Hello World!";

## Start function
def start():
    if (condition):
        printf("something else");
        if (other condition):
            printf("another thing");
    if (condition):
        printf("something else");
    printf(text2print);
    return 0;'''

code = code.replace("    ", "\t")

new_code = ""
prev_level = 0
for line in code.splitlines():
    new_level = 0
    for char in line:
        if char == "\t":
            new_level += 1
        else:
            break
    for i in range(prev_level - new_level):
        new_code += "\t"*(new_level+((prev_level - new_level)-i-1)) + "}\n"
    prev_level = new_level
    if line.endswith(":"):
        line = line[:-1] + " {"
    new_code += line + "\n"
new_code += "}\n"

print(new_code)
```

This outputs with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * text2print = "Hello World!";

## Start function
def start() {
        if (condition) {
                printf("something else");
                if (other condition) {
                        printf("another thing");
                }
        }
        if (condition) {
                printf("something else");
        }
        printf(text2print);
        return 0;
}
```